# How to mark employees which are also manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to determine whether an employee is any other employee's manager.

Given this table:

```
Employee    Employee's Manager
----------  ------------------
Bob         CN=Lisa              
Amanda      CN=Lisa              
James       CN=Art               
Frank       CN=Amanda            
Amy         CN=Art
```

I need this:

```
Employee    Employee's Manager  Employee IS Manager
----------  ------------------  -------------------
Bob         CN=Lisa              N
Amanda <--  CN=Lisa              Y <--
James       CN=Art               N
Frank       CN=Amanda <--        N
Amy         CN=Art               N
```

Because Amanda appears in the "Employee's Manager" column in another employee's row, I need to derive this, adding the additional "Employee IS Manager" field.

I've gotten as far as this (wrong!) subquery for the additional "IS Manager" field, but I do not know how to add it as a column in a subquery:

```
select 
    a.* , 
    (select 'Y' as IsManager 
        where exists (select * from Employees b where b.Manager like '%' + @x+ '%' )
    )
 from Employees a
```

But I do not know how to make `@x` refer to Amanda in the Employee column in the other row.

**EDIT**: I should note that I am not necessarily looking for a "subquery" solution.  A JOIN solution, or any other kind of solution is fine for my purposes.  Thanks.

Comment: Do the strings in the "employees manager" column all really start with `CN=`? They shouldn't...

Comment: Yes, they do all begin with "CN=".  They are the results of an Active Directory LDAP query.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close but you need a `case` expression:

```
select e.* , 
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from Employees m
                          where m.Manager like '%=' + e.employee_manager
                         )
             then 'Y' else 'N' end
        ) as isManager
from Employees e;
```

Note that I tweaked the logic for matching so "Anne" and Roseanne" do not get confused.  If the manager always starts with `'CN='`, then use `like 'CN=' +`  instead.

Comment: Thanks.  Been doing TSQL for YEARS, and never knew about `%=`  heh

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace . .  . That is a string constant in this context, although I think it is also a (very) rarely used assignment operator in other contexts.

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace '%=' is used to match 'CN=' part of manager's name. % to match CN and = to match =. %=  together is not a special thing.

Comment: @D. Woods.  Hey!  How come it let you add less than 6 characters?  Or, did removing my "WAT?" line *remove* more than 6 chars, making it OK?  haha  So, I could have done that myself?

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace, I was merely a "reviewer" of _your_ edit.  I guess in the review mode, S.O. isn't as picky about the number of characters changed?  When I saw your comment/note, I just figured that it was a complaint that you expected a reviewer to remove (so I did).

Comment: @D.Woods
Cha-ching!  ;-)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `outer apply` to get your desired result. Here through outer apply we are getting 'Y' when an employee is also a manager other wise it's returning null. Coalesce() is used to convert null to 'N'.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table Employees (Employee    varchar(50),employee_Manager varchar(50));
 insert into Employees  values('Bob',         'CN=Lisa');              
 insert into Employees  values('Amanda',      'CN=Lisa');              
 insert into Employees  values('James',       'CN=Art' );              
 insert into Employees  values('Frank',       'CN=Amanda');            
 insert into Employees  values('Amy',         'CN=Art'   );
```

Query:

```
 select 
    a.*,coalesce(isManager,'N')[Employee IS Manager]
  from Employees a outer apply(select 'Y' from Employees b where b.employee_manager='CN='+a.Employee)manager (isManager)
```

Output:

| Employee | employee_Manager | Employee IS Manager |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | CN=Lisa | N |
| Amanda | CN=Lisa | Y |
| James | CN=Art | N |
| Frank | CN=Amanda | N |
| Amy | CN=Art | N |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=37e0f583a3fd0326e527183c49060c22)*